# How can I change the var of a javascript function by pressing a key on the keyboard?

Tags: javascript, function, var, keystroke

I have a piece of code here and I want to be able to press a key (f.i. the "1" key) so var isRunning = false. When I press another key (f.i. the "2" key) var isRunning should change back to isRunning = true.

It needs to be as simple as possible (javascript/html), no jquery. I just want to alter the value of this var with a definable keystroke.

This is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var pages=[];
pages[0]="page0.html"
pages[1]="page1.html"
pages[2]="page2.html"

var time = 33000; 
var currentIndex = 0; 
var isRunning = true;

function pageChange() { 
    if(isRunning){
        if(currentIndex == 0){ 
            pages = shuffle(pages); 
            console.log(pages);
            currentIndex = pages.length; 
        }
        currentIndex--; 
        document.getElementById("frame").src=pages[currentIndex]; 
        console.log(currentIndex);
    }
    setTimeout(function() { pageChange(); }, time);
};

window.onload = function(){
    pageChange();
}


</script>
```

Comment: Just google "javascript key events" and you will find dozens of solutions

Comment: JQuery is javascript..

Comment: @greenhoorn no JQuery is a javascript library

Comment: @rdans That's pedantic...

Comment: Well I googled quite a bit on this, but I cannot find anything on how to key-change only the var within a function, instead of an entire function. Yes, I prefer not to use the jquery library. :)

Comment: @greenhoorn not really. There's a big difference between a programming language and a library/framework which can be used within a programming language.

Comment: @rdans It doesn't have its own syntax, it's simply plain JavaScript. So yes, it is Javascript and yes, it is a library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Should do the trick ;)

```
 document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
        if(event.keyCode == 49) { //keycode 49 is '1'
            isRunning = false;
        }
        else if(event.keyCode == 50) { //keycode 50 is '2'
            isRunning = true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: This did the trick indeed! Thanks a lot. Is it also possible to use only the "1" button to change the var consecutively from true to false, to true again etc.?

Comment: Of course it is, just use isRunning = !isRunning in the if statement and remove the else if statement

Answer (score 0):

Since your `isRunning` is in global scope, you can just catch a keydown event for the number keys. For example if you want to catch the event on the whole page, go like this:

```
window.onkeydown = function(e){
    switch(e.keyCode){
        case 49:
        case 97:
            isRunning = false;
            break;
        case 50:
        case 98:
            isRunning = true;
            break;
    }
}
```